# Creating a slideshow that has onClick effects..Works in Fiddle, but not in my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have the HTML page linked to the jQuery file that I downloaded. I know this works because I have a different slideshow working on the same page, but I wanted a different kind and would like the images to slide on a timer as well as on click. I have the Fiddle which works perfectly, but how do I get this to work in my webpage? http://jsfiddle.net/hYEzV/1160/ 
The code below is from my website files. The javascript is what is creating the issues.

HTML:

```
<div class="ourinfo">
            <div id="slidecontain">
                <div id="Stage_Previous_Div_Button" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0%; top: 0%; width: 50%; height: 80%; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 1;"></div>
                <div id="Stage_Next_Div_Button" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 50%; top: 0%; width: 50%; height: 80%; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 1; "></div>
                <img class="pic" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ha4fxv7SUQk/UEII0DdN6DI/AAAAAAAAAVI/QnEUjsDxi-M/s1600/black%2Babstract%2Bwallpapers5.jpg" />
                <img class="pic" src="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2012/264/d/c/inanis___wallpaper_pack_by_hmalvao-d5fg61h.jpg" />
                <img class="pic" src="http://dark.pozadia.org/images/wallpapers/78056903/Dark/Abstract%20Dark%20Planets.jpg" />
                <img class="pic" src="http://images2.alphacoders.com/111/111200.jpg" />
            </div>
    <div>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yaou-qomTrg"></iframe>
    </div>
    <footer>Colerain High School Chapter<br>William Koonce, Sarah Matevia, Jacob Rigby<br>Colerain High School, Cincinnati OH<br>Theme~</footer>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slidecontain
{
    position:relative;
    width:49%;
    height:300px;
    z-index:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}

#slidecontain img
{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $("#Stage_Previous_Div_Button").hover(function(){
  $(function(){

    $("#Stage_Previous_Div_Button").css( 'cursor', 'url(http://i.imgur.com/r2FFM1i.png), auto' );

});
});

$("#Stage_Previous_Div_Button").hover(function(){
  $(function(){

    $("#Stage_Next_Div_Button").css( 'cursor', 'url(http://i.imgur.com/kGYEBSo.png), auto' );

});
});

$("#Stage_Previous_Div_Button").click(function() {
prev();
});

$("#Stage_Next_Div_Button").click(function() {
next();
});


$(".pic").hide();

$(".pic").show();


function prev() {
    $("#slidecontain img").last().prependTo('#slidecontain').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#slidecontain img").first().fadeIn(1000);


}
function next() {
    $("#slidecontain img").first().appendTo('#slidecontain').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#slidecontain img").first().fadeIn(1000);


}

next();
setInterval(next, 7000);
```

The header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="information">
    <meta name="keywords" content="far trek, enterprises, travel, tokyo, japan, london, england, venice, italy, paris, france, cruise, fly, vacation">
    <meta name="author" content="Sarah Matevia, William Koonce, Jacob Rigby">
    <title>Far Trek Enterprises</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slide2.js"></script>

</head>
```

**Update: Timer for pictures are working, but can not click the picture.

Comment: Kitty add that to your question

Comment: sorry! still learning

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the jquery library properly?  I used to have this very same problem when I was just learning jquery.  Try replacing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

with this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to learn more about including libraries and file structures, I recommend [this course on the command line](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/).  While not technically about javascript, it will help you understand file structures and how to navigate them.

Comment: The library is included properly. It works for my other slideshow that is on the webpage. It looks like the timer is working, but not the onClick.

Comment: well I didn't know if it needed to be onClick in the jQuery or click in the jQuery. I know in HTML it is onClick. I can try switching it.

Comment: no no, you're right about .click.  You know, I don't ever use 'click,' because I was having problems with it way back in the day.  I always use .on('click', function(){   /*callback*/  });

Comment: I will try that way for now on, but it isn't changing anything in the outcome, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I needed to add the ready command for the entire function. jsFiddle does that for you. So the resulting script will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#previous").hover(function(){
  $(function(){

    $("#previous").css( 'cursor', 'url(http://i.imgur.com/r2FFM1i.png), auto' );

});
});

$("#next").hover(function(){
  $(function(){

    $("#next").css( 'cursor', 'url(http://i.imgur.com/kGYEBSo.png), auto' );

});
});

$("#previous").on('click', function() {
prev();
});

$("#next").on('click', function() {
next();
});


$(".pic").hide();

$(".pic").show();


function prev() {
    $("#slidecontain img").last().prependTo('#slidecontain').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#slidecontain img").first().fadeIn(1000);


}
function next() {
    $("#slidecontain img").first().appendTo('#slidecontain').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#slidecontain img").first().fadeIn(1000);


}

next();
setInterval(next, 7000);
});
```